# Problemas ao compilar BitBucket +Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bitbucket

Eu uso o Eclipse para compilar/modificar servidores de jogos emulados em Java e sempre usei a Assembla, ela usa o `build.xml` para compilar e nunca tive problemas.
Tenho um projeto que preciso compilar e está no Atlassian/BitBucket e por todas as maneiras que tentei, não consegui compilar o projeto!

O link é este: [Projeto](https://bitbucket.org/EvTeam/l2evil/src/656285510179006152a62e888308d9091d7fd2a5?at=master) e se alguém me der uma luz, ficarei imensamente agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

Como este projeto possui o arquivo pom.xml, ele está estruturado com Maven. O processo de build do Maven segue um [ciclo de vida](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) com fases de construção e distribuição da aplicação.

Para fazer o build pelo Eclipse clique com o botão direito no projeto e escolha a opção *Run as* e, em seguida, *Maven Build*.

Mais informações [aqui](http://blog.caelum.com.br/processo-de-build-com-o-maven/).

Comment: Para mim não aparece essa opção, tu teria um tutorial para que eu possa seguir?
Muito obrigado!